# Poweshell script to create shortcut with properties

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-4.0

I am follwing this [msdn](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/27ffb0811ca761741502feaefdb591aebf592193/Samples/DesktopToasts/CPP/DesktopToastsSample.cpp#L203) document. I want to create a shortcut with two properties `AppUserModelId` and `ToastActivatorCLSID`. How can I achieve this with powershell.

Basically I want to convert the following code and create shortcut via powershell script.

```
_Use_decl_annotations_
HRESULT DesktopToastsApp::InstallShortcut(PCWSTR shortcutPath, PCWSTR exePath)
{
    ComPtr<IShellLink> shellLink;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&shellLink));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = shellLink->SetPath(exePath);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            ComPtr<IPropertyStore> propertyStore;

            hr = shellLink.As(&propertyStore);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                PROPVARIANT propVar;
                propVar.vt = VT_LPWSTR;
                propVar.pwszVal = const_cast<PWSTR>(AppId); // for _In_ scenarios, we don't need a copy
                hr = propertyStore->SetValue(PKEY_AppUserModel_ID, propVar);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    propVar.vt = VT_CLSID;
                    propVar.puuid = const_cast<CLSID*>(&__uuidof(NotificationActivator));
                    hr = propertyStore->SetValue(PKEY_AppUserModel_ToastActivatorCLSID, propVar);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        hr = propertyStore->Commit();
                        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                        {
                            ComPtr<IPersistFile> persistFile;
                            hr = shellLink.As(&persistFile);
                            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                            {
                                hr = persistFile->Save(shortcutPath, TRUE);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return hr;
}
```

I wrote a simple script to create a shortcut however not sure how can I stamp the said two props

```
function set-shortcut {

param ( [string]$SourceLnk, [string]$DestinationPath )

    $WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell

    $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($SourceLnk)

    $Shortcut.TargetPath = $DestinationPath

    $Shortcut.Save()

    }
```

Comment: [make-shortcut-with-appusermodelid](https://github.com/Robertof/make-shortcut-with-appusermodelid)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the pre-built modules/scripts from the MS powershellgallery.com to determine if they solve your use case vs rewrite from scratch. Unless this is a learning effort. Even with that, looking at the underlying code of the below may help.

```
Find-Module -Name '*shortcut*'

# Results
<#
Version   Name                        Repository Description
-------   ----                        ---------- -----------
2.2.0     DSCR_Shortcut               PSGallery  PowerShell DSC Resource to create shortcut file.
...
1.0.6     PSShortcut                  PSGallery  This module eases working with Windows shortcuts (LNK and URL) files.
...
#>


Find-Script -Name '*Shortcut*'
# Results
<#
Version Name                       Repository Description   
------- ----                       ---------- -----------   
...                        
1.0.0.0 New-DeskTopShortCut        PSGallery  Create a desktop shortcut
#>
```

Comment: I went through these. However this is very simple script to create a shortcut. I am particularly interested in stamping two said props.

Comment: Regarding a normal window url shortcut, those properties are not there/visable. You can see this using `Get-Item -Path 'D:\Documents\PowerShell\Non-Admin user for WMI - YouTube.URL| Get-Member -Force | Format-Table -AutoSize` or normal desktop app shortcut or AppX shortcut, all return the same set.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that an item has several properties. What you want to do is assign a value to a certain property.

```
Get-Item -LiteralPath $NomeDoArquivo | Set-ItemProperty -Name $Propriedade -Value $Valor -Force
```

Answer (score -1):

I also did not know there is a module in `PSGallery` for this task, so I wrote a script some time ago, see if it helps:

[Set-Shortcut.ps1](https://github.com/metablaster/WindowsFirewallRuleset/blob/master/Modules/Ruleset.Utility/Public/Set-Shortcut.ps1)

**EDIT:**

You only need to add `$InformationPreference = "Continue"` at the top of the script to have informational messages show up.

Comment: I am particularly interested in setting AppUserModelId and ActivatorCLSID. Something like `$Shortcut.AppUserModelId= "MyApp"`

Comment: Can you right click any desktop shortcut and set this value? or can you set it using `WScript.Shell`? This is a task for C# commandlet programming,PowerShell being a scripting language is not the right tool to accomplish this.

Comment: _> PowerShell being a scripting language is not the right tool to accomplish this_ Says who?